# Heroku review app looks for app.development.json instead of production

Tags: angular, heroku, gitlab-ci, npm-scripts

I have a multi-package angular project with the main one needing the other two to be successfully built. We host our project on GitLab and through its CI runners, we want to create dynamic review apps that run in production mode to view any visual change made in a merge request. The problem is that even though, I have specified that it should run in production mode, it runs in development and asks for app.development.json which isn't present.

In angular.json, I have specified that whenever building a package, the output folder would be `/dist/<package-name>/`

I have created a server.js file that takes all the static files and serves them.

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use('/assets/config/app.production.json', express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist/registrar/assets/config/app.production.json'), {
  lastModified: false,
  cacheControl: false,
  etag: false
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), '/dist/registrar/')));
// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd() + '/dist/registrar/index.html'));
});
```

I have added `heroku-postbuild` script which does the following

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm i && cd packages/theme && npm i && cd ../common && npm i && cd ../.. && npm run ng -- build -- common && npm run ng -- build -- registrar --aot --prod --source-map=true"
```

Let's break down why I need this script. I have a main package named registrar which needs the theme package and the common package to run. I have a dependencies in each package that's why I'm running `npm i` thrice. 
I also have set source maps to be true, to have a debugging capability during the review stage.

The gitlab ci passes (as the app is created successfully) but when I am redirected to the review app I get an error that the app.development.json is missing.

Whenever I rename the app.production.json to app.development.json, the app runs successfully, but in development mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our case, we had to disable optimization and change the `heroku-postbuild` script to `...  npm run ng -- build registrar --optimization=false --aot --prod --source-map=true`